# ByteBuffer.wrap came out unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

I used ByteArray to create a new string, but the results came out unexpectedly. Here was my code

```
void foo(byte[] data, ...)
{
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data, 0, 15);
    String msg = new String(byteBuf.array());
    Log.i("FOO", String.format("ByteArraySize=%d\t\tMsgLen=%d,%d", data.length, byteBuf.array().length, msg.length()));
}
```

The length of the byte array is 518400. But the log info shows:

**ByteArraySize=518400  MsgLen=518400,518400**

rather than

**ByteArraySize=518400  MsgLen=15,15**

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected result.

According to the JavaDoc from `ByteBuffer.wrap()`:

> Wraps a byte array into a buffer.
>
> The new buffer will be backed by the given byte array; that is, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa.

And `ByteBuffer.array()`:

> Returns the byte array that backs this buffer  (optional operation).
>
> Modifications to this buffer's content will cause the returned array's content to be modified, and vice versa.

That means that `ByteBuffer.array()` will return the very same array that you wrapped with `ByteBuffer.wrap()`.

Comment: Could you kindly explain what is the use case of the wrap function called with offset and length arguments since the new buffer is actually backed by the same byte array?

Comment: I use a ByteBuffer if I want to access a byte array sequentially as stream of bytes, shorts, integers etc (`getInt()`, `putInt(int)` and others). The `ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[], int offset, int length)` is a nice variant to `ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[])` if I only want to access part of the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

`array()` returns the byte array that backs the buffer.

It's the same object. i.e. `byteBuf.array() == data`

To construct a string with subarray of `data`, use:
`String msg = new String(data, 0, 15);`